# Check only 1st row of duplicated values for some condition

Tags: r

I am a newbie to R. Can someone help me with this

For below df,  I need to check only the first row of each Item and if column "value = 0" then only I need to keep both the rows for that Item

df

```
Item    city   price  value
 A      Delhi   10      0
 A      Mumbai   5      2
 B      Delhi   10      1
 B      Mumbai   5      2
```

Here for Item A, we will check the first row and value =0 so we will keep both the rows of Item A. But when we check the first row of Item B there value=1 so we remove both the rows of Item B.

output

```
Item    city   price  value
 A      Delhi   10      0
 A      Mumbai   5      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'Item', and `filter` the groups having the 'first'  'value' as 0

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(Item) %>%
     filter(first(value) == 0)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Item [1]
#  Item  city   price value
#  <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
#1 A     Delhi     10     0
#2 A     Mumbai     5     2
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
subset(df, Item %in% subset(df, !duplicated(Item) & !value)$Item)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Item = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), city = c("Delhi", 
"Mumbai", "Delhi", "Mumbai"), price = c(10L, 5L, 10L, 5L), value = c(0L, 
2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `ave`

```
df[with(df, ave(value == 0, Item, FUN = function(x) x[1L])), ]

#  Item   city price value
#1    A  Delhi    10     0
#2    A Mumbai     5     2
```